# Blocks of consecutive letters in a random word

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

Let $X$ be an alphabet with $d$ letters, and we consider words over $X$. A block in a word is a subword of the form $xx...x$ for some letter $x\in X$. Every word $w$ is uniquely partitioned on blocks $w=v_1v_2\ldots v_k$, where consecutive blocks contain different letters.

**Question 1:** What is the expected value of the number of blocks in a random word of length $n$?

**Question 2:** What is the expected value of the maximal length of a block in a random word of length $n$?

**Edit:** I have found answer to Question 2 for |X|=2 in the book "Analytic Combinatorics", Prop. V.1: the mean maximal length $\sim \log_2 n$.

Comment: What is the probability distribution of the letters in a word? Are letters i.i.d.?

Comment: Yes, I consider uniform distribution.

Comment: What did you try and at what step did you get stuck?

Comment: I tried for the binary alphabet |X|=2. For Question 2, we can write a recursion for the number of words with $\leq l$ consecutive letters. Then I got the generating function $\frac{1-z^{l+1}}{1-2z+z^{l+1}}$. I am not sure what to do for |X|>2. I guess the answer is $\frac{1-z^{l+1}}{1-dz+(d-1)z^{l+1}}$

Comment: You can count words with at least $l$ maximal consecutive letters: count the different ways to choose $l$ consecutive indices from $n$ and multiply by $d$ for the choice of letter that would repeat, call it $S_l$. Then probability of maximal length being $l$ is $\frac{S_{l+1} - S_{l}}{n^d}$.

Comment: For Question 1, you can find the probability of the number of blocks being $k$ using again a counting argument with the help of [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). I know these counting based expressions get real messy real fast, but do these ideas help?